# Odoo domain can't filter Unit(s) and Hour(s) from domain

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9

I have many2one field and trying to filter units of measure by name:

```
product_uom = fields.Many2one('product.uom', 'Unit of Measure', required=True, domain="[('name', 'in', ['m', 'Hour(s)', 'mile(s)', 'Day(s)', 'unit(s)'])]")
```

xml field:

```
 <field name="product_uom"/>
```

The problem is that in product_uom dropdown I can't find Unit(s) and Hour(s). What can be wrong with these field names?

P.S. for example if I make simple sql like that in my PgAdmin `select * from product_uom where name in ('Unit(s)', 'Hour(s)')` everything is fine.

---

**Solved:**

Changed my code into:

```
@api.multi
def get_domain(self):
    lang = self.env.context.get('lang')
    domain_list = ['m', 'Hour(s)', 'mile(s)', 'Day(s)', 'Unit(s)']
    if lang and lang != 'en_US':
        result = self.env['ir.translation'].search_read([
                                                    ('lang', '=', lang), 
                                                    ('src', 'in', domain_list)])
        domain_list = [rec['value'] for rec in result]
    return [('name', 'in', domain_list)]
```

Comment: Could it be that the user's language is not English and the UOMs names for `Hour(s)` and `Unit(s)` are translated to the language of the user and therefore the values are not found when the domain is applied (`product.uom` field `name` is translatable)?

Comment: Yep that was a problem. When I change language to English - everything is ok. So I need to find another i will filter with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can user search read to extract the 
translated value of units:

```py
 product_uom = fields.Many2one('product.uom', 'Unit of Measure', required=True, 
   domain=lambda self: self.get_domain())



 @api.multi
 def get_demain(self):
    """get default domain for uom taking languange in considiration"""
    lang = self.env.context.get('lang')
    domain_list = ['m', 'Hour(s)', 'mile(s)', 'Day(s)', 'unit(s)'])]
    if lang and lang != 'en':
        # language is not english
        result = self.env['ir.translation'].search_read([
                                                        ('lang', '=', lang), 
                                                        ('src', 'in', domain_list),
                                                        ('name', '=', 'product.uom')], 
                                                ['value'])
        domain_list = [rec['value'] for rec in result]

    return [('name', 'in', domain_list)]
```

I didn't try the code but i think you can make it better than this hope this helps you. like may if there is no translation for this words in user language ....etc

Comment: I updated my question. Changed your code a bit and it works!

Comment: but i think i deserve to accept my answer after all the idea is everything in programming ^^

Comment: as i told you this works if every unit has a translation you need to check if all the item returned from the search are the same in original list too.

Comment: Yes I force with a problem that 'm' unit has no translation. I added it to translation and everything now is ok.

Comment: But you should do that in code just check the result and add missing units.  And you didn't accept my anwser mmmm not good hhh

Comment: i was just joking with you, don't hate me for that